# Spark jdbc.write to mysql with null error

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, null

I am creating a column in a Dataframe that gets set to null (via None) but when sent to JDBC write I get "Can't get JDBC type for null". Any help would be appreciated.

```
update_func = (when(col("SN") != col("SNORIGINAL"), None)) 

aPACKAGEDF = aPACKAGEDF.withColumn('SNORIGINAL_TEMPCOL', update_func)
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for null
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:175)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:175)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType(JdbcUtils.scala:174)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$20.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:635)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$20.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:635)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:635)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `None` in

```
update_func = (when(col("SN") != col("SNORIGINAL"), None))
```

has no defined type. Use casted literal instead. For example if type should be string (`VARCHAR` or similar):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

update_func = when(col("SN") != col("SNORIGINAL"), lit(None).cast("string"))
```

Comment: Sometimes you cant see the forest for the trees. Your suggestion worked like a charm!